# map perl looping from value

Tags: perl, mason

I am not able to understand why following code is not working.

```
<%method getvivekBox>
  <%args>
   $BoxName
  </%args>

  <%perl>
    return {
      type        => 'vivek',
    };
  </%perl>
</%method>




<%method getAll>
 <%args>
  $BoxGroup
  $indexex
 </%args>
  <%perl>
    my $x =  map { $m->comp('SELF:getvivekBox' , BoxName => "$BoxGroup-$_"); } @$indexex;

    return $x;
  </%perl>
</%method>
```

I am calling `getAll` with arguments , box and `(1..10)`. It is returning 11 but expected behavior for me it should return 10 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` on a list produces another list. You are assigning the result of the `map` to a scalar, thus getting the number of elements assigned to `$x`.

Change `$x` to `@x`, or put `[]` around the `map` (to make `$x` an array reference).

Comment: Won't you be getting the number of elements in the list?

Comment: Nope, give it a try: perl -E '$x=(1,1,1,17); say $x' - prints 17. If you put parenthesis around the $x, you get the first element, by the way.

Comment: @asjo No it's definitely the count in this case. See `perl -e '@a=(4,5,6);$x=map {$_} @a; print "$x\n";'`

Comment: You're right that a list in scalar context evaluates to the last element in the list, but in this case, you're calling a function (`map`). Different functions return different things in scalar context, so you should consult the [documentation for `map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html): "In scalar context, returns the total number of elements so generated." Sobrique and AKHolland are correct.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: more correctly, the comma operator in scalar context gets you the last element in the list.

Comment: @ysth Thank you, I kind of felt like I was missing something (I thought it was magic).

Comment: Thanks for putting me straight, my test was too simple. D'oh. (It is confusing to me that map does something else than a list in scalar context, but that is no excuse.)

Comment: @asjo: lists don't ever get produced in scalar context; instead, every operator or builtin function does what seems like the most reasonable thing to do, and the documentation will tell you what that is.

Comment: @ysth Indeed. One of the warts of Perl 5 I don't hit that often, fortunately.